# How to check for an empty Telerik Kendo editor content

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a simple form with a couple of dropdowns a multi-select and an editor.
The dropdowns both have an initial item which has a text value of Please Select and a value of ''. On submission I have the following bit of Javascript/JQuery that checks that I have values in my dropdowns, multi-select and editor.

```
    var validFlag = true;

    var dropdownlist = $("#addNew_dTeam").data("kendoDropDownList");
    if (dropdownlist.value() == "") {
        validFlag = false;
        errorMsg = "<li>Select Team</li>"
    }

    dropdownlist = $("#addNew_dType").data("kendoDropDownList");
    if (dropdownlist.value() == "") {
        validFlag = false;
        errorMsg += "<li>Select Entry Type</li>"
    }

    var multiSelect = $("#msServers").data("kendoMultiSelect");
    if (multiSelect.value() == "") {
        validFlag = false;
        errorMsg += "<li>Add at least one Server or select N/A</li>"
    }

    var editor = $("#diaryComments").data("kendoEditor");
    if (editor.value() == "") {
        validFlag = false;
        errorMsg += "<li>A comment is mandatory</li>"
    }
```

The code works fine for the dropdowns and multi-select, but the check for empty editor content does not work. My editor is empty yet the if (editor.value() == "") is not true.

Comment: Are you correctly react on your validFlag variable later in code? Because code looks correct. Try debug that but condition will be true in case of empty editor. Look on this [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/OJida)

Comment: @Ademar looking at your Dojo example you have used both editor.value() and editor.val()... I will experiment further...

Comment: Yea, exactly, value can be retreived more choises, anyway your code should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While editor is empty, consider one blank space so your condition will be like `if (editor.value() == ' ')` (there is one space between single quote)...

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UGaVo)

hope so it will work for you...

Comment: Thanks... Adding a single space worked which is strange as looking at Ademar's dojo solution he has no spaces and his code also works.

Comment: So should I check for both editor.value == "" or editor.value == " "?

Comment: Final solution was to use $.trim(editor.value()) == ""